What is the literal meaning of the word 'cross' in the 'star-crossed lovers'?
I see 'star-crossed' defined as "not favored by the stars : ill-fated" in Merriam Webster. Does the 'cross' mean ​

'4 [transitive] cross somebody to oppose somebody or speak against them or their plans or wishes'
'2 [intransitive, transitive] to pass across each other' as in 'paths cross' so they will not meet again

or something else?

This was answered on ELU years ago: 'Star-crossed lovers' are two people who, although in love, have natal charts which are 'crossed'. 'Star-crossed' is, effectively, a technical term in astrology indicating that there are aspects of the charts of the two lovers which, when compared, show that the forces of fate will tear them apart or, at least, prevent them from being happy together. There's plenty more in that and other answers, but it's mostly Lit Crit and History. This isn't really much of an English Learners question, though.

Thank you FumbleFingers very much for the link and explanation.

The original 'star-cross'd lovers' (who gave rise to the phrase) are Romeo and Juliet in William Shakespeare's play of the same name. An older meaning of 'cross' as a verb is 'to thwart, oppose, go counter to' (Oxford English Dictionary). To say that 'the stars' are opposed to your plans (that they cross you) is to say that your plans are doomed to failure. The idea arose in a time when many people believed in astrology.

Thank you Michael very much for the answer.  I wonder why Shakespeare would use the word cross instead of oppose or object. I know it may be his literary style.  Does the cross have any special connotation that other similar words do not?  The 'cross' word has its meaning near the bottom of its definition, so it is not an easy word for non-native speaker to understand it as 'oppose' unless your fluency is at an advanced level.

@user1026669 - Shakepeare wrote the play in the 16th century (it was first performed in 1597). He was well know for inventing phrases and expressions. He probably felt 'crossed' scanned (the prologue, like much of Shakespeare's work, is blank verse)  better than 'oppose'. 'Object' does not mean the same thing.

We still use the verb.  Don't cross me, I'm warning you!

Thank you Michael for correcting me for the word 'object'. Thank you TimR for the comment.
